# Error running Docker container on a VMWare hosted Windows 10 machine

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a windows 10 machine that is hosted on VMWare (vShpere 6.2 ) . I'm trying to run docker container on this machine and I've installed 'Docker for Windows' on the machine.
When running the hello-world container I'm getting the following error.

```
c:\> docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: container b631237e1d24f87c3a578a753f550ce30aaaf1b5e21b984db5da7b59a83d7c20 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: No hypervisor is present on this system. (0xc0351000)
```

The same instructions works on  physical machine with windows 10. Hyper-V is enabled on the guest windows-10 machine.

I've found instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization but this is related to Hyper-V and not vmware.

Are there any instructions on how to run docker on a VMWare hosted windows OS?  My purpose of using 'Docker for Windows' is so that I'd be able to run windows-continer on the windows-10 guest OS on vware.

Answer (score 5):

Docker for Windows [requires hardware virtualization support](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization) to run anything via Hyper-V. This means that VMWare has to expose Intel VT-x or AMD-V to the guest OS. This is disabled by default in vSphere, so you have to enable it manually to get docker support in the guest.

[From the vSphere docs:](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-2A98801C-68E8-47AF-99ED-00C63E4857F6.html)

> 1. Right-click the virtual machine and select Edit Settings.
>
>    a. To locate a virtual machine, select a datacenter, folder,
>      cluster, resource pool, host, or vApp.
>
>    b. Click the Related Objects tab and click Virtual Machines.
> 2. On the Virtual Hardware tab, expand CPU, and select **Expose hardware-assisted virtualization to guest OS**.
> 3. Click OK.

Comment: I have Expose hardware-assisted virtualization to guest OS checked on my VM machine and in Windows 10 1903 task manages virtualization is checked. But Docker Desktop (Linux containers) is not starting up.

Comment: A similar virtual machine that runs Windows 2016 with the same conuration runs Docker EE.

Comment: Maybe the processor E5-2630L is the case

Answer (score 1):

You could try to turn virtualization on in your BIOS, according to an [answer](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1477#issuecomment-383128633) to a similar question. Look for “Intel VT-x”, “Intel Virtualization Technology”, “Virtualization Extensions” or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) which doesn't require Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

Power on the machine and open the BIOS (as per Step 1). Open the Processor submenu The processor settings menu may be hidden in the Chipset, Advanced CPU Configuration or Northbridge. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT) or AMD-V depending on the brand of the processor.

Hyper V is the native virtualization technology of Microsoft.  VM-ware uses the virtualization  provided the processor, which is disabled most of the time. If its disabled you can't run docker machine on your machine. Please try this option of enabling the virtualization on your PC.

Comment: I am currently using a WMWare 6.5 server that virtualizes virtual machines. We installed Docker Desktop on one of them, which won't start. The machine has the Expose hardware-assisted virtualization to guest OS option set, but Docker for Linux or Windows does not work anyway. I don't have access to the WMWare bios, but my guess is that virtualization must be enabled.

A similar virtual machine that runs Windows 2016 with the same conuration runs Docker EE.

Comment: Maybe the processor E5-2630L is the case

Comment: This surely is the issue of Nested Virtualization. The Virtualization need to be enabled for the processor and then nested virtualization need to be enabled for VM.
- Verify that the virtual machine compatibility is ESXi 5.1 and later.
- Verify that Intel VT-x or AMD-V is enabled in the BIOS(Host Machine) so that hardware assisted virtualization is possible.

you need not have access for VM-Ware BIOS the answer is for the Bare Metal OS and not VM.

Please follow the link https://communities.vmware.com/thread/605185

Answer (score 1):

**install latest vmware workstation > 15.5.5 version**

which has the support of Hyper-V Host

> With the release of VMware Workstation/Player 15.5. 5 or >, we are
> very excited and proud to announce support for Windows hosts with
> Hyper-V mode enabled! As you may know, this is a joint project from
> both Microsoft and VMware

https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html

**i installed VMware.Workstation.Pro.16.1.0**

and it fixed my issue now i am using docker and vmware same time even my window Hyper-V mode enabled

Answer (score 0):

Install VMWare WorkStation 16.x.x.
Settings -> Option -> Advanced -> (ticked) Disable side channel mitigations for Hyper-V enabled hosts